# Read json with meaningless keys into pandas data.frame with correct Dtype

Tags: python, json, pandas

In a project, I receive json that I need to read into a pandas data.frame.

The format looks like the one below (with more columns and rows):

```
{    "a;b;c;d":{
      "1":"100;14/09/2020;0.5;XK3",
      "2":"NA;17/09/2020;0.95;NA",
      "3":"102;NA;NA;KZ2"}}
```

I'm able to split the strings, but my types are not what I want. Is there an automated way to convert the columns in `u`?

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO("""
    {    "a;b;c;d":{
          "1":"100;14/09/2020;0.5;XK3",
          "2":"NA;17/09/2020;0.95;NA",
          "3":"102;NA;NA;KZ2"}}
          """)

df = pd.read_json(TESTDATA)
df.head(10)
vnames = df.columns[0].split(';')

u = (df[df.columns[0]].str.split(';', expand=True)
             .set_axis(vnames, axis=1, inplace=False)).convert_dtypes()

print(u.head(10))

print(u.info())
```

I want the Dtype to be `int64, datetime64, float64, str`.

Comment: Your real data have the same form? A dict with a single key?

Comment: @Corralien, yes, my real data has the same form. There are multiple files and more columns in the files, but overall it is the same.

Comment: What’s “incorrect” about your json?

Comment: @balmy, the json format is valid, but the key-value pairs are meaningless. It is a table embedded in a json in a horrible way.

Comment: So it's "correct" JSON, but not as you want it. Please edit your question title to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

TESTDATA = StringIO("""
    {    "a;b;c;d":{
          "1":"100;14/09/2020;0.5;XK3",
          "2":"NA;17/09/2020;0.95;NA",
          "3":"102;NA;NA;KZ2"}}
          """)

df = pd.read_json(TESTDATA)




df.head(10)
vnames = df.columns[0].split(';')

u = (df[df.columns[0]].str.split(';', expand=True)
             .set_axis(vnames, axis=1, inplace=False))



u = u.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('NA', np.nan)

u = u.to_json()
u = pd.read_json(u).convert_dtypes()

print(u.head(10))

print(u.info())
```

Comment: It keeps the dates as string, but it is more or less what I was looking for. So if I don't get an answer that does the job for the dates in the next few days, I'll accept this one as it is a significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly typecasting the string values before creating the DataFrame, like in this example:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

s_src = '''{    "a;b;c;d":{
      "1":"100;14/09/2020;0.5;XK3",
      "2":"NA;17/09/2020;0.95;NA",
      "3":"102;NA;NA;KZ2"}}'''

s = json.loads(s_src)

# per-column type conversion
typeconv = [int, pd.to_datetime, float, str]

for k1, subd in s.items():
    cols = k1.split(';')
    rows = []
    for k, v in subd.items():
        row = v.split(';')
        conv_row =[]
        for cvt, r in zip(typeconv, row):
            # screen for missing values
            if r == 'NA':
                conv_row.append(None)
            else:
                # apply the conversion function for this column
                conv_row.append(cvt(r))
        rows.append(conv_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

Comment: my objective is to avoid manually typecasting (hardcoding) the values. Else, I could use something like `numericCols = ["c"] \\ u[numericCols] = u[numericCols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')`